# How can I make my select2 element work with datatables and pagination?

Tags: pagination, datatables, jquery-select2

My select2 element is working well with my jquery datatable:

```
  var table = $('#table').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "data/table.json",
            "dataSrc": "",
        },


        "columnDefs": [
             {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return '<select class="form-control select2" ><option selected value="one">one</option><option value="two">two</option></select>';
            },
            "targets": 0
            },
        ],

       "columns": [
            {
                "data": "content"
            },
        ],
       "dom": "<row></row>",

     initComplete: function () {
       $('select').select2();
     },
 });
```

But it is working only on my first page of my pagination. When I go to the second page or just show more results, it is not working anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `draw.dt`function is initializing the select2 element on every pagination page change:

```
 initComplete: function () {
       $('#table').on('draw.dt', function() {
            $('select').select2();
        });
   },
```

Comment: While code-only answer may help it always better to add some explanation

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @peace_love, can you please explain where draw.dt comes from? I'm facing the same issue and posted it except with local data and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

With data-width attribute:

```
function Select2() {
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).off('change');
        var width = $(this).attr("data-width") || '100px';
        var x = this.required;
        $(this).select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap4',
            width: width,
            dropdownAutoWidth: true
        });
        if (x) {
            $(this).next().children().children().each(function() {
                $(this).css("border-color", "#f8ac59");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This only modifies the actual width of the field and nothing to do with pagination

Comment: you need work around this code by your, but with an added class that you can added to pagination "on.init" event of datatable you can solve this problem. you not have given any Html+javascript example correctly to make a example response...